# install CPAN module ClearCase::CtCmd

Tags: perl, cpan

I need to install the CPAN module [`ClearCase::CtCmd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ClearCase%3a%3aCtCmd). I have downloaded the module [CtCmd-1.09](http://search.cpan.org/~alevenso/CtCmd-1.09/CtCmd.pm). After running the command `perl Makefile.PL` I am having the following errors:

```
perl Makefile.PL
Looking for ClearCase version   7       Found   7.1
Looking for gcc version 2.7     Found   3.4
Looking for SunOS       5.7     Found   5.8
Checking if your kit is complete...
Use of uninitialized value in chdir at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/File/Find.pm line 741.
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/File/Find.pm line 741.
Looks good
Could not open 'CtCmd.pm': No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 3079.
```

I mention that the perl version is  **v5.8.5.** In the INSTALL file it is stated that "The `ClearCase::CtCmd` module requires Perl **v5.6.1** or **v5.8** or later."

Comment: Perl `5.8.x`; I've used `windows 2000` back then so that tells something about it's age and why update is recommended.

Comment: The current version of [ClearCase::CtCmd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ClearCase%3A%3ACtCmd) is 1.11.  Even if you're stuck with an archaic version of Solaris and an archaic version of Perl, you might find that a less archaic version of ClearCase::CtCmd will work better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of machine is this on? Solaris? Doesn't ClearCase come with its own version of Perl that already includes `ClearCase::CtCmd`?

```
Use of uninitialized value in chdir at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/File/Find.pm line 741.
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/File/Find.pm line 741.
Looks good
```

`File::Find` is a standard Perl module. The uninitialized value in `chdir` does not *look good*.

```
Could not open 'CtCmd.pm': No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.5/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 3079.
```

`ExecUtils/MakeMaker` is calling `ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm` and is trying to write your Makefile. I have a feeling it's suppose to locate where `CtCmd.pm` is located from `File::Find` and with `File::Find` failing, `MakeMaker` can't create the Makefile.

I'm looking at the [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/ALEVENSO/CtCmd-1.09/Makefile.PL) and see that it requires `$ATRIA_ROOT` to be set, or otherwise, it's inferred as being at `/opt/rational/clearcase`. Could this have something to do with it?

No. Doesn't look like it. Otherwise, you wouldn't have gotten the report on the ClearCase version. And, I guess the system is Solaris because that's the only place where the `gcc` version is being searched.

I think it's time to do a bit of munging in the `Makefile.PL` program to see what it's doing. I notice in line #218 is `WriteMakefile(%opts);` I would add a little routine to print out this `%opts` subroutine (probably using `warn` instead of `print`). This subroutine is from [ExtUtils::MakeFile](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) which actually writes the Makefile. It might give you a clue to what's going on.

Unfortunately, the problem looks like it has to do with the way `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` is working. Using Perl 5.8.5 means you have an older, buggier version of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`. You can look at the release notes of [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.99_02/Changes) and see if that offers you any clue. Perl 5.8.5 is no longer supported. It's a very, very old version of Perl.

Comment: I have solved this eventually, I have installed a newer perl version.